# In triangle $ABC$, $\angle C = 48^\circ$. $D$ is any point on $BC$, such that $\angle CAD = 18^\circ$ and $AC = BD$. Find $\angle ABD.$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In  triangle $ABC$, $\angle C = 48^\circ$. $D$ is any point on $BC$, such that $\angle CAD = 18^\circ$ and $AC = BD$. Find $\angle ABD.$

I tried to make some constructions: draw a line through $D$ parallel to $AC$; draw a line through $C$ which makes $66$ degrees with $AC$. None of them have been useful. It feels like I am trying to force the formation of congruent triangles, and that doesn't work. Please help.

[image: Diagram created using GeoGebra]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Draw in black the triangle $ABC$ with angle $48^\circ$ at $C$, and $AD$ with angle $18^\circ$ at $A$. This ensures the blue angles $114^\circ$ and $66^\circ$. Choose $D'\in BC$ such that  $|D'C|=|BD|=|AC|$. This gives the red angles $66^\circ$ and $66^\circ-18^\circ=48^\circ$. This implies that $|AD'|=|AD|$. The triangles $AD'C$ and $ADB$ are therefore SAS-congruent with the same angles at $D'$ and $D$. This shows that the green angle $\angle ABD=48^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: thank you. may I know what software you use to make geometry diagrams?

Comment: @rishikesh: It's CANVAS DRAW3 for Mac.

Comment: @rishikesh There are a lot of software for that. Geometer's Sketchpad, Geogebra (Free), Desmos (Free/online).

Answer (score 3):

Let $E$ be a point such $ED=AD$ and $EB=CD$ and that $A, E$ lie on the same side of line $BC$. Then $\triangle DEB \equiv \triangle ADC$ so $\angle BDE = \angle CAD$ and therefore
$$\angle EDA = \angle BDA - \angle BDE = \angle DCA + \angle CAD - \angle BDE = \angle DCA = 48^\circ.$$
Since $ED=AD$, we have $$\angle AED = 90^\circ - \frac 12 \angle EDA = 90^\circ - \frac 12 \cdot 48^\circ = 66^\circ.$$
But also $\angle DEB = \angle ADC = 180^\circ - 48^\circ - 18^\circ = 114^\circ$. Hence $\angle AED + \angle DEB = 180^\circ$ and therefore $E$ lies on $AB$. It follows that
$$\angle ABD = \angle EBD = \angle DCA = 48^\circ.$$

[image]

Special thanks to Calum Gilhooley for providing a picture.

Comment: how do we know that point E exists? if we draw circles centred at A and B with the chosen radii, it is not immediately apparent to me that they intersect.

Comment: @rishikesh These circles intersect because the sum of their radii is bigger than the distance between the centers. This follows from triangle inequality in $ACD$ and from the assumption that $AC=BD$.

The intended definition of $E$ is: build a triangle $DEB$ congruent to $ADC$. It is clear that this exists.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it would be using sine rule. In ACD, we have

$$\frac{\sin 114}{AC} = \frac{\sin 48}{AD}$$

In triangle ABD, we have

$$\frac{\sin(114-B)}{BD} = \frac{\sin B}{AD}$$

If you solve these equations, using AC=BD, we have
$$\tan B = \frac{\sin 48}{1+\cot 114\cdot\sin48}$$

$$\implies \tan B = 1.1107$$

Hence $B = 48^0$

Comment: I think you've made a mistake in the last step, the answer is 48 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\measuredangle ABC=x$. Then $\measuredangle BAD=114^\circ-x$. By sine theorem we have:
$$
BD\stackrel{\triangle BAD}=AD\frac{\sin(114^\circ-x)}{\sin x}
\stackrel{\triangle CAD}=AC\frac{\sin 48^\circ}{\sin 114^\circ}\frac{\sin(114^\circ-x)}{\sin x}\\
\implies \frac{\sin 48^\circ}{\sin 114^\circ}\frac{\sin(114^\circ-x)}{\sin x}=1
\implies \frac{\sin x}{\sin(114^\circ-x)}=\frac{\sin 48^\circ}{\sin 66^\circ}
\implies x=48^\circ.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's my method, it's VERY confusing and messy, so there's probably a better method.
Using the sine rule: $$\frac{AC}{\sin114}=\frac{AD}{\sin 48}$$
so $$AC=BD=\frac{AD\sin114}{\sin48}$$
Cosine rule: $$AB^2=AD^2+\frac{AD^2\sin^2 114}{\sin^2 48}-2\frac{AD^2\sin 114\cos 66}{\sin 48}=AD^2 (1+\frac{\sin^2 114}{\sin^2 48}-2\frac{\sin 114\cos 66}{\sin 48})$$
So $$AB=AD \sqrt{1+\frac{\sin^2 114}{\sin^2 48}-2\frac{\sin 114\cos 66}{\sin 48}}$$
Sine rule (again): $$\frac{AB}{\sin66}=\frac{AD}{\sin ABD}$$
so $$\frac{AD \sqrt{1+\frac{\sin^2 114}{\sin^2 48}-2\frac{\sin 114\cos 66}{\sin 48}}}{\sin66}=\frac{AD}{\sin ABD}$$
Cancelling $AD$ from both ides and rearranging to find $ABC$ should get you your answer. I hope that helped! (It'd probably help to draw a sketch.)

Comment: Rather than using cosine rule, I think sine rule with some re-arrangement would make a better approach, just check my solution if it's on the same lines

Comment: Don't you use the cosine rule to get $\tan$?

Comment: No, just expand the $\sin(A-B)$ formula and re-arrange so that you get something of the form $p \sin A = q \cos A$